# Shell Command to Create a text file in all sub-directories

Tags: linux, shell

Hi everyone is there any linux command to create a custom text file in current directory and its sub directories

For example,
I would like to turn this directory tree:

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── A
│   └── B
├── 2
│   └── A
└── 3
    ├── A
    └── B
        └── I   
9 directories, 0 files
```

into this

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── A
│   │   └── downloadedFrom.txt
│   ├── B
│   │   └── downloadedFrom.txt
│   └── downloadedFrom.txt
├── 2
│   ├── A
│   │   └── downloadedFrom.txt
│   └── downloadedFrom.txt
├── 3
│   ├── A
│   │   └── downloadedFrom.txt
│   ├── B
│   │   ├── downloadedFrom.txt
│   │   └── I
│   │       └── downloadedFrom.txt
│   └── downloadedFrom.txt
└── downloadedFrom.txt

9 directories, 10 files
```

i want to make a **txt file** in all directories (txt file content: my website name) is there any way?
or is there any way to **overwrite files content** in sub directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only a single `find` command:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "yourwebsite" > "$1"' _ {}/downloadedFrom.txt \;
```

or, alternatively, using bare `bash` with `globstar` option (since `bash` 4):

```
shopt -s globstar
for dir in . **/; do echo "yourwebsite" > "$dir/downloadedFrom.txt"; done
```

Comment: Hi can we overwrite files content with custom text (in sub directories) excluding one file ?? if there is any command please tell

Comment: @Sadam Which file do you want to exclude?

Comment: i want to exclude instructions.html file

Comment: In my answer, only the files whose names are `downloadedFrom.txt` are overwritten, so the file `instructions.html` is already exempt from being overwritten.

Comment: no, i mean here is files list

`-[Gamz] 
--Subfolder-- [games] 
file: readme.html 
file: list.txt 
file: links.htm 
file: downloadedFrom.txt 
file: tutorial.txt` 
i want to overwrite all files (html,txt,htm,etc) and want to put my sitename in all files  excluding one file which is tutorial.txt i need that command which can igrone tutorial.txt file in all directories and overwrite all other files

Comment: That is a very different question. Ask it as a separate question giving sample input and expected output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906092/shell-command-to-overwrite-files-in-all-sub-directories-excluding-one-file please check if you can help thanks

Comment: what are the use of underscore _ in this command and if ```{}``` is containg directory names than why ```echo``` command redirecting to ```$1``` what is $1 here

Comment: @Sadam `_` is just a placeholder for the positional parameter `$0` (any other string could be used instead of `_`). When the shell is invoked with `sh -c command_string arg0 arg1 ...`; `arg0` will be assigned to `$0`, `arg1` will be assigned to `$1`, and so on, before `command_string` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in `find . -type d` ; do echo "mywebsite.com" > $dir/downloadedfrom.txt ; done
```

Is this what you are looking for, sort of? The find command iterates through all directory type items in the current directory, and then we echo the contents of the file to a new file in all those directories. However, this will overwrite stuff that's already in those directories, so watch out!

Comment: Hey this for your help this command is working but not overwriting files can you please check







`|   |-- downloadedfrom.txt
|   |-- s
|   |   |-- d.txt size 0.00
|   |   `-- downloadedfrom.txt size 0.01
|   |-- t
|   `-- t.txt size 0.00
|-- xx
|   |-- downloadedfrom.txt size 0.01
|   `-- f
|       |-- downloadedfrom.txt size 0.01
|       `-- fff
|           `-- downloadedfrom.txt size 0.01`

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.... I tried writing a new file called "downloadedfrom.txt" in a directory with different contents, then ran this again and got (what I think is) the desired result

Comment: Hi this command is working and creating downloadedfrom.txt file in all sub directories but there are some empty files in directories like file1.txt d.txt t.txt this command is not inserting text into those files is there any way to fix that too?

Comment: Do you want to replace those empty files contents with your new content or remove them? That seems like a separate command you'd call.

Comment: Yes replace them with site name

Comment: Then you would probably use something similar, but look for all file types (-type f in the find command) and cat the same string into those as well.

Comment: This won't work if directory names contain space characters.